Calculating median using cte and groupby SQLite
I want to calculate the median using SQLite. My variable of interest is the result of combining multiple tables together. I tried to follow this solution, but the output shows null-values.
My query looks as follows:
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT m.round,
           f.f * (m.won * o.odds - 1) AS r
    FROM matches m
    INNER JOIN f
    ON f.match_id = m.match_id
        AND f.player_id = m.player_id
    INNER JOIN odds o
    ON o.match_id = m.match_id
        AND o.player_id = m.player_id
)

SELECT round,
       COUNT(*) AS n,
       ROUND(AVG(r), 3) AS avg_r,
       ROUND(AVG(
           CASE counter % 2
               WHEN 0 THEN CASE WHEN rn IN (counter / 2, counter / 2 + 1) THEN r END
               WHEN 1 THEN CASE WHEN rn = counter / 2 + 1 THEN r END
           END
       ) OVER (PARTITION BY round), 3) median_r,
       ROUND(MIN(r), 3) AS min_r,
       ROUND(MAX(r), 3) AS max_r
FROM (
    SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY round ORDER BY r) rn,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY round) counter
    FROM cte)
GROUP BY round

What am I doing wrong?
Edit
The first 25 rows of cte looks as follows:
round,f
R32,5.434575672657226
R32,4.662480056088388
R32,4.205099630165803
qualifier,3.845729295512344
qualifier,3.6497091129740933
R32,3.5610333161115517
QF,3.346344544760134
,3.220331570271259
R16,3.1176543317988417
,2.9963085045132583
R16,2.814289763584883
R32,2.8081039581780614
R32,2.7321826199364434
R32,2.5748915361198526
R32,2.5748753002036873
R16,2.574872228663704
R16,2.574872228663704
R32,2.574872228663704
R32,2.574872228663704
R32,2.574872228663704
R32,2.574872228663704
R32,2.574872228663704
R32,2.574872228663704
R32,2.574872228663704
,2.574872228663704
SF,2.188892038343798


What are you doing wrong - posting a question with no sample data and no expected result.

You're right. I added some sample data

Created table rounds with your sample data ...   see fiddle here
Comments in code.
--    S Q L :
SELECT  round, Max(median_f) as median_f, 
        Max(Case When cnt = 1 Then 'Just one value - not a median' End) as note
FROM  ( Select  Coalesce(r.round, 'round_is_null') as round,  
                Case --  upper middle row per round
                    When Row_Number() Over(Partition By Coalesce(r.round, 'round_is_null') Order By r.f) 
                        = (Count(*) Over(Partition By Coalesce(r.round, 'round_is_null')) / 2 ) + 1 
                    Then Case -- odd number of values for round - median in this row  
                              When (Count(*) Over(Partition By Coalesce(r.round, 'round_is_null')) + 1) / 2
                                  != Count(*) Over(Partition By Coalesce(r.round, 'round_is_null')) / 2
                              Then Round( f, 3 )
                              -- even number of values for round - median is average of this and previous row's value
                         Else Round( ( f + Lag(f, 1) Over(Partition By Coalesce(r.round, 'round_is_null') Order By r.f) ) / 2, 3 ) 
                         End
                End as median_f, 
                Count(*) Over(Partition By Coalesce(r.round, 'round_is_null')) as cnt
        From    rounds r
        Order By Coalesce(r.round, 'round_is_null'), r.f
      )
GROUP BY round  
ORDER BY round

/*    R e s u l t :
round            median_f  note 
-------------  ----------  -----------------------------
QF                  3.346  Just one value - not a median
R16                 2.695
R32                 2.575
SF                  2.189  Just one value - not a median
qualifier           3.748
round_is_null       2.996                                  */

The same result could be fetched without aggregation and group by (using same subquery) with filter in Where clause:
SELECT  round, median_f, 
        Case When cnt = 1 Then 'Just one value - not a median' End as note
FROM   ( above subquery )
WHERE   median_f Is Not Null
ORDER BY round

You can test results here
The sample of upper middle logic:
group   row    val    median  note
------  ---  -----  --------  -------------------------------------
A         1      2         2  count rows 1 - not a median

B         1     20   -|
B         2     30   -|-> 25  upper middle row (even row count)

C         1      2
C         2      2   --->  2  upper middle row (odd row count)
C         3      3

D         1      2
D         2     10
D         3     10  -|
D         4     20  -|-> 15   upper middle row (even row count)
D         5     20
D         6     20

E         1      2
E         2     10
E         3     21
E         4     23   ---> 23  upper middle row (odd row count)
E         5     23
E         6     38
E         7     38


perfect, thank you for your time and effort

seems like your 'CASE' and 'AVG' functions are not correct. Something like this will do.
    WITH ordered_cte AS (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY round ORDER BY r) AS rn,
           COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY round) AS counter
    FROM cte
),
median_cte AS (
    SELECT round,
           CASE
               WHEN counter % 2 = 1 THEN MAX(r) OVER (PARTITION BY round ORDER BY rn ROWS BETWEEN (counter - 1) / 2 AND (counter - 1) / 2)
               ELSE AVG(r) OVER (PARTITION BY round ORDER BY rn ROWS BETWEEN counter / 2 - 1 AND counter / 2)
           END AS median_r
    FROM ordered_cte
)
SELECT round,
       COUNT(*) AS n,
       ROUND(AVG(r), 3) AS avg_r,
       ROUND(MIN(r), 3) AS min_r,
       ROUND(MAX(r), 3) AS max_r,
       ROUND(MAX(median_r), 3) AS median_r
FROM ordered_cte
GROUP BY round;


Hi thanks for taking a look, but there is some syntax missing in your median_r- definition; FOLLOWING or PRECEDING expected, got ')'
